# Unable to create layer for LinearLayout(Crashing in only Galaxy j4+, j6+)

Tags: webview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I want adding "transitionGroup:true" ,but I want sure this code cant create error or crash on different devices?

Comment: Where is the code?